# use \b without deleting a character in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

While I am aware that \b is used to delete a character in Python3, this time however, I intend to use \b without deleting a character.
My code is as follows:

```
BUILD_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..\build')
```

However, I get the following error upon build execution:

```
fs.errors.InvalidCharsInPath: path 'F:\wagtail bakery\wagtail-bakery-master\examples\site\example\.uild' contains invalid characters
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: maybe do backslash two times?

Comment: as @ppwater suggested just escape your backslash so its `\\b` instead of `\b` so python looks at it as a `\\` character

Comment: Thank you @ppwater and karan Shishboo! Helped preventing from deleting the character however didnot solve my problem as I am still getting the same error of InvalidCharsInPath. Will take a different approach now, thanks though